# Proof that $\sin$ is continuous by open sets on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

The open set definition of continuity is:

$f:A \to B$ is continuous $\iff$ $U_{B}\in\tau_{B} \implies f^{-1}U\in\tau_{A}\ \forall U_B$, where $\tau_A$ and $\tau_B$ are the topologies of $A$ and $B$.

I believe that in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ this reduces to:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous $\iff$ $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon \implies |x-y|<\delta$,

since $U_{B} = \{f(x) : |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\}$ and $U_A = \{x : |x-y|<\delta\}$.

My textbook (Nakahara) makes it very clear the the converse definition is *not* true; i.e., you can't just show that open sets in the domain map to open sets in the range, you must show that the inverse image of an open set in the range is an open set in the domain.

I'm trying to prove that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Now, I can easily do the following by choosing $\delta = \epsilon/2$:

$$
|x-y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
2\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right| < \epsilon \\
2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right| < \epsilon \\
2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right| < \epsilon \\
\left|\sin x - \sin y\right| < \epsilon
$$

But I'm operating under the impression that I must show the reverse, and it's not at all clear to me that the step:

$$
2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right| < \epsilon \implies 2\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right| < \epsilon
$$

is true in this direction (although it naturally follows the other way around).

So my questions are:

1. Am I correct in thinking that I need to show the converse?
2. If so, how do I do it?
3. If not, what is the meaning of Nakahara's statement?

Comment: Why call open set definition of continuity instead of standard name as $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity?

Comment: Because I'm doing a course on differential geometry and that's the definition they want me to use

Comment: Your $\implies$ is pointing the wrong way in your definition. You need to show (at your chosen value of $x$) that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|y - x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. It's useful to note that, for any $x, y$, we have $|\sin y - \sin x | < |y - x|$ - think of the graph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

The "open set definition" says that $f$ is continuous if for all open $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}U$ is open.

The "$\epsilon-\delta$ definition" says that $f$ is continuous if for all $a$ in $X$, and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|a-b|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(a) - f(b)|<\epsilon$ for $b$ in $X$.

This means your first line (where you defined continuity) is incorrect.

However, your proof that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous looks correct!

There is no need to show the converse, as it is clearly not true because $\sin(x) - \sin(n\pi x) = 0$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The converse has nothing to do with continuity of $\sin$ anyway.

**EDIT**
Using the open set definition:

Suppose $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open. This is not necessarily an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (although it is a countable union of intervals). We know that arbitrary unions of open sets are open. Therefore, suppose we can show that the inverse image $f^{-1}U_i$ of every open interval $U_i$ is open. Then any open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\bigcup_{i\in K} U_i$ for some set $K$. Hence the inverse image of $U$ is $\bigcup_{i\in K} f^{-1}U_i$ which is a union of open sets, which is open. Therefore it suffices to just consider open intverals.

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. I will show that $\{x: \sin(x) \in U\}$ (the inverse image of $U$) is open. Remember that a set is open if there is an open ball contained in the set, centered at any point in your set. For $\mathbb{R}$ this is saying a set is open if given any point in the set, you can find an open interval containing that point which is also contained in the set.

Let $c\in \{x: \sin(x) \in U\}$. This means $\sin(c) \in U$. Because $U$ is open, there is an interval $(\sin(c) - \epsilon, \sin(c) + \epsilon)$ contained in $U$. But now this is equivalent to $|\sin(c) - k|=|\sin(c) - \sin(y)| <\epsilon$, and the question is "can you find a $\delta$ so that $|c-y|<\delta$ makes this true?" The proof ends up becoming the same even though I started with a different approach.

Comment: I think this is where I'm getting stuck. $U \subset Y$ is an open subset, so $U = \{f(x) : |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon \}$. So if I assume $U$ is open, and I want to show $f^{-1}U$ is open, does that not mean I need to go from $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ to $|x - y|<\delta$? (Because $f^{-1}U$ is $\{x : |x - y|<\delta \}$.)

Comment: Your last step is wrong. Just because $f^{-1}U$ is open, it doesn't mean it will be of the form $\{x:|x-y|<\delta\}$. Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398928/how-is-the-epsilon-delta-definition-of-continuity-equivalent-to-the-following-st

Comment: Ah, okay, yes that makes sense. In that case how do I show that $f^{-1}U$ is an open set? Both the range and domain have the usual topology, so saying $f^{-1}U$ is an open set is equivalent to saying it's an open interval.

Comment: I added some extra information

Comment: Okay, so the logic is: Suppose $U_B = \{\sin x\}$ is an open set. Then there must be at least one $\sin c \in U_B$ such that $\sin c$ is in an open interval, $|\sin c - \sin x_0| < \epsilon$. Now I need to show that the inverse image, $U_A = \{x : \sin x \in U_B\}$, is an open set. Therefore, I need to find some $\delta$ such that for some $d \in U_A$, $|d - x_1| < \delta$. Last question: why can I take $c = d$ and $x_0 = x_1$? Is it because every element of $U_A$ must be contained in an open interval for it to be an open set, so you can choose an arbitrary element?

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Given $U_B = \{\sin x\}$ is an open set, there must be an open interval contained within it. Hence $\exists\sin c \in U_B$ s.t. $|\sin c - \sin x_0| < \epsilon$. Now, if the inverse image, $U_A = \{x : \sin x \in U_B\}$, is open, then it must also contain open intervals. Hence there must be an open interval of some radius $\delta$ such that $c$ is in the interval. Therefore, find some $\delta$ s.t. $|c-x_0| < \delta$ and there's the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Sorry I've been a bit slow, this has been my first proof based maths course since first year of undergrad.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the "inverse image of open sets are open" definition of continuity you could begin by noting that there are three types of basic open intervals in $[-1,1]$

1. $(a,b)$ where $-1<a<b<1$
2. $(a,1]$
3. $[-1,b)$

Then point out the the inverse image under $\arcsin$ of each of these three types of basic open set is a countable union of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then let $U$ denote an open set in $[-1,1]$.

Then for each $y\in U$ there is a basic open set $V$ of one of the three types above such that $p\in V\subseteq U$, and the inverse image of $V$ under the $arcsin$ function is an open set containing the inverse images of $y$.

Thus the inverse image of $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Suppose I have an open set in the range which overlaps the peak of $\sin$, so $(a,b) = (a,1] \cup (1,b)$. The preimage of this is $(\arcsin a, \pi/2] \cup \emptyset = (\arcsin a, \pi/2]$, which is not open? Obviously I've done something wrong, since $\sin$ is continuous, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: No, if $0<a<1<b$ then the pre-image of $(a,b)$ is the interval of $(\arcsin a,\pi-\arcsin a)$ together with the union  of all translations of that interval by even multiples of $\pi$. There would be a similiar infinite union of open intervals in the case of $a<-1<b<0$.

Comment: Oh, is it just that the preimage is actually $(\arcsin a,\pi/2] \cup [\pi/2,\pi - \arcsin a) \cup \emptyset = (\arcsin a,\pi - \arcsin a)$ which is open? Yes! Thank you!

Comment: The empty set is completely unnecessary in this regard.

Comment: Note that you only need show that $y=\sin x$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ onto its range $[-1,1]$. And that if $-1<y<1$ then the intervals $[-1,y)$ and $(y,1]$ are open sets in $[-1,1]$. So it is unnecessary to consider open intervals $(a,b)$ where $b>1$ or where $a<-1$.